# Cascade effect when shadows turned on

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, tango

I am not able to cast shadows with Tango Unity app.

When I turn on shadows in Unity, my object has a cascade effect and the background is frozen or black.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I've seen Tango Apps with 3D objects that cast shadows. So I know it's possible.  If I turn off shadows, I'm good, but I want shadows!

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: I have no code.  I am using the prefabs and example objects that come with the Tango SDK.   I have Tango Manager, Tango Point Cloud and Tango Camera in my scene along with an 3D object.

Comment: Fixed it!  Found the answer in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068186/cascade-effect-with-3d-gameobjects-tango-unity-android

Comment: I had to set Clear Flags (under camera) to Solid Color and made the color black.